# Prevent a user from visiting certain pages until registered

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an ASP.NET website. There are some pages on my sit that I want him to see only if he is a registered user. If not, he should be redirected to the appropriate page. Should I be checking this on the Page_load event that the user is  logged in or not?

If the user types the name of the URL, this would still work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I do for some of simplest websites. It uses typical [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). From global.ascx.cs:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var unsecuredPages = new[]
                             {
                                 "test.htm",
                                 "email.htm"
                             };

    bool letThrough = unsecuredPages.Any(s => Request.RawUrl.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(s));
    if (letThrough)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
        !Request.RawUrl.Contains(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

You explicitly specify pages that should be visible to all users and all other requests will be redirected to the login page. My web.config looks something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="480" name="xyz" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>
</authentication>
<location path="Styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just add <location> elements for those two unsecured pages like you have for your styles folder?

Comment: Not really, I just prefer to have it there rather than in a config file, so that other people don't mess with it. You might have the opposite requirement.

Comment: When I write the above code `var unsecuredPages = new[]`
 in Global.asax.cs, it asks for data type to be specified in after new :-/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make an class and in that class you can check user is registered or not and inherit that class on that pages that are required for registered users.

You can do using also forms authentication as above @HeavyWave ways.